# Firebase Authenticated but data not able read or write

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I have implemented Firebase authentication with Gmail, Facebook,Twitter.

I have successfully logged in firebase, Then i have changed Database Authentication rules to below.

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": false,
    ".write": false
  }
}
```

In firebase console it is showing login users list but while retrieve data it is showing permission denied.  Could   you please help me to resolve this issue?

if i change above settings to true i can able to read and write data.

Comment: You've updated the database rules to block all read and write queries to the database. So you're getting permission denied. See https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/

Comment: If you want to allow authenticated users to read / write you should update your rules `{ "rules": { ".read": "auth.uid != null", ".write": "auth.uid != null" } }`

Comment: Dear @sketchthat really thanks. i have implemented. it's really worked. i missed this. thank you so much.

Answer (score 2):

Setting both to false will deny read/write access to all users. You can use the `auth` syntax in your security rules to identify whether or not a user is logged in.

For example, to allow read/write access for logged in users only your rules would look like -

```
{ 
  "rules": {
    ".read": "auth != null",
    ".write": "auth != null"
  }
}
```

Comment: OP didn't ask that only authenticated users should be allowed to read and write database, so this answer is not fully correct

Comment: It sounded like that was implied, but agree the example I've given may not be completely relevant.

Comment: Dear @Dude Coder thank you so much. it working. i missed this.

Answer (score 0):

As the name (Database Authentication rules) suggests, these rules are for your `Firebase-Database`, that who should be allowed to read and write the data on your database and who should not be.

So, in your case, what have you done is- You've set both `read` and `write` to `false`. This means no one will be able to either read or write to your database. And that's what is happening (You're not able to write to the database).

But, when you set both of them to `true`, then everyone will be able to read and write.

So, if you want everyone to be able to read and write to your database, then your rules will look like this:

```
{ "rules": {
   ".read": true,
   ".write": true"
}}
```

If you want nobody to be able to read and write to your database, like temporary disabling your website or app:

```
{ "rules": {
   ".read": false,
   ".write": false"
}}
```

If you want everyone to be able to read your database but want only authenticated members to be able to write to your database like they've purchased the premium account and now they can edit the site, then the rules would be:

```
{ "rules": {
   ".read": true,
   ".write": "auth != null"
}}
```

If you want only authenticated members to be able to read and write to your database, then the rules would be:

```
{ "rules": {
   ".read": "auth != null",
   ".write": "auth != null"
}}
```

And if you want to explore more about how this stuff works. Then here is the link to official documentation: [Understanding Firebase Database Rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/)